# GCP Composer V2 Airflow DAG - Not able to pass XCom from PythonOperator to BashOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

We are trying to create an airflow DAG in GCP Composer V2 to copy all tables in one project:dataset to another project. We need to use bq cp command to copy the tables because we have nearly 1000+ large tables with partitioning and we need to copy these a couple of times and keep cost down. We have:

1. PythonOperator to get the list of only base tables in the source dataset and
2. BashOperator to run the bq cp command.

But we are not able to pass the list of tables from PythonOperator to the BashOperator. We have tried several options but cannot seem to get it to work. We can see the table names from get_table_names_for_dataset task in XCom but when we do the xcom_pull we get the value "None". Please help.

Two calls are as below.

```
get_table_names_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="get_table_names_for_dataset",
    python_callable=get_table_names,
    op_kwargs={"client": client, "dataset_ref": f"{source_project}.{dataset}"},
    do_xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag,
)

# Copy tables using bq cp -f
copy_tables_from_dataset = BashOperator(
    task_id=f"copy_tables_from_{dataset}",
    bash_command=f"""
    set -e  # Exit on any error
    for table in $TABLE_NAMES; do
        bq cp -f {source_project}:{dataset}.$table {target_project}:{dataset}.$table
        echo "Copied table {{ table }}"
    done
    """,
    env={"TABLE_NAMES": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_table_names_task') }}"},  # Pass XCom values as env var
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: Why are you using the bash operator and not still your python code? And did you consider copying datasets? And, more globally, why copying table? You can only share views between project and keep a single source of truth